# How to set prenote for \cite globally using biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

How can I set prenote for `\cite` globally with the possibility to pass an individual  option via optional parameter to a single `\cite` command?

It should work like this:

```
\cite{key} --> \cite[see][]{key}
\cite[otherSuffix][]{key} --> \cite[otherSuffix][]{key}
```

Answer (score 4):

If I have understood correctly the question, every citation is introduced by "see" unless an optional parameter is given.  This can be obtained by redefining the `prenote` bibmacro.

```
\renewbibmacro*{prenote}{%
  \iffieldundef{prenote}
    {\printtext{see}}
    {\printfield{prenote}}%
    \setunit{\prenotedelim}%
}
```

Comment: I think you mean: `\renewbibmacro*`.

Comment: @jon Yes, `\renewbibmacro*` is better, though, with `\newbibmacro*` `biblatex` will just issue a warning and fall back to `\renewcommand*`